# Provide DevOps extensions functionality via REST-API

Tags: typescript, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-extensions

We are using the Sprint Goal DevOps extension [vsts-sprint-goal](https://github.com/keesschollaart81/vsts-sprint-goal).
I need to set the sprint goal via REST call. What is the easiest way to integrate a REST-endpoint into the extension that can be accessed like a normal DevOps REST-endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to expose a REST API from an extension.

But... Extension data is stored as one or more files in dedicated extension storage.

> Because settings are stored as documents, we need to provide a collection name, indicating where to store the document. To keep things simple, when working with the setValue()/getValue() methods, the collection name is always the special name '$settings'. The previous call issues a PUT Request at the following endpoint:

```
GET _apis/ExtensionManagement/InstalledExtensions/{publisherName}/{extensionName}/Data/Scopes/User/Me/Collections/%24settings/Documents
```

> The request payload would be the following:

```
{
                "id": "myKey",
                "__etag": -1,
                "value": "myValue"
}
```

> ### REST APIs
>
> Assuming this snippet is executed after the value has already been set, you should see an alert message containing the text "The value is myValue". The getValue method is again a wrapper around the REST APIs, issuing a GET request to the following endpoint:

```
GET _apis/ExtensionManagement/InstalledExtensions/{publisherName}/{extensionName}/Data/Scopes/User/Me/Collections/%24settings/Documents/myKey
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/extend/develop/data-storage?view=azure-devops

As an alternative *you* could host an API on something like Azure Functions that wraps around the Extension Data to provide a proper REST API around the Extension Data API.